# Codeigniter/PHP assigning a value to a variable in the Constructor 

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor, global-variables

I'd like to define a global object variable that I could use in several of the functions in my controller, `Items`.

Here's my code that doesn't work:

```
class Items extends CI_Controller {

 private $varname;

 function Items(){
  parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('items_model');
    $folder_id=416;
    $this->varname=$this->items_model->getFilesById($folder_id);
 }

 function index(){
   var_dump($this->varname);    
 }

}
```

So `$this->varname` doesn't work as evidenced when I go to the url: `localhost/items/index` the printed ouput is this:

```
array(0) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of PHP, the constructor may not be called. Try changing

```
function Items(){
```

to

```
function __construct(){
```

and see if that fixes the problem.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.

That may be what is causing your problem.

Comment: -@Greg thanks, I'm using PHP 5.3.1, unfortunately that didn't change the problem, its probably some Codeigniter weirdness, might there be any other way? Do I have to use the `$this` keyword to make it a global variable?

Comment: You have to use `$this->` to refer to that instance's `files` variable. Where is `files` declared?

Comment: `files` isn't declared anywhere. I thought I could just assign `files` to the `items_model` data I retrieved. I don't need it to be called `files`. It can be anything just as long as I can call this variable throughout the class.

Comment: You can, I was just wondering if files was already defined by codeigniter, and that is what was causing the problem. Maybe choose another variable name and declare it using `private $varname;` at the top of the class, before the functions.

Comment: hi @Greg, ok I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, that didn't work. I edited my question to show you exactly what I did and what the output was if that is helpful.

Comment: Try var_dumping `$this->items_model->getFilesById($folder_id)` in the constructor. Maybe the getfilesbyid is the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, `var_dump($this->items_model->getFilesById($folder_id))` prints same empty array  `array(0) { }`. Ok problem solved. Assigning `$this-varname=416;` allows it to be `echo`'d in the `index()` function as expected. I'll fix my model.